# Ruby app using devise for authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, crud

I am building a simple app that allows members to create a trip. Only one trip. I wanted to get some practice using the devise gem so that setting up the application with sign in, sign out, etc is easy and efficient, but I need some help. Right now I have two models: member & trip, neither of which have a controller.

This is my sign up form and when I click submit, somehow a member is created in the database even without a member controller? How do I redirect this to a different page after submit is pressed?

I'm just a little confused on what I should be adding since devise is doing a lot of the work behind the scenes.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a controller to do this.

```
class UserController < Application::Base
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(email: params[:email], password: params[:password],      password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to <page you want to redirect to>
  else
    render new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise offers some macros that you can override to choose what paths you want to redirect to.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path'
  end
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration))

EDIT:

Create a file in your controller folder called `registrations_controller.rb`.  Put this code into that file.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path'
  end
end
```

Replace `/an/example/path` with whatever path you want to redirect to after someone signs up.  Then modify your `config/routes.rb` to point to that controller by adding this line:

```
devise_for :members, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Then, you may need to edit your `config/application.rb` by adding this line

```
config.paths['app/views'] << "app/views/devise"
```

If you encounter a "MissingTemplate" error.

Comment: Yes, but when I click sign up, it automatically takes me back to home. Lets say I want to redirect to another route/path, how/where would I insert that?

Comment: The source I linked to was a step by step instructions on how to modify Devise default behavior.  But I have edited my answer to include the instructions

Comment: Awesome! Do you think there is a similar way to do that for after successful sign in too? I've built crud apps before, but devise is a whole new thing.

Comment: According to their docs you would use `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`

Answer (score 0):

1. The *user*(or in you case *member*) controller simply talking resides in devise gem internals.
2. To redirect a user to `user/home` you may define `user_root` route in your `routes.rb` file in this way:

   `get 'user/home', as: 'user_root'`

   Read more [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers).

Comment: Yes, but when I click sign up, it automatically takes me back to home. Lets say I want to redirect to another route/path, how/where would I insert that?

Comment: Change `'user/home'` for what you need (in the above line).